# assets not copying while ng build in production

Tags: angular, production

i am working on the angular 4. i have added new svg image in the assets/images folder. then i changed in the angular-cli.json file also. while doing ng build in local it copying the new svg file to build/libs/images. But when am doing production build it is not copying the file.

Comment: Could you please share your code.

Comment: @lgorDiy  "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "./libs/images/spin.gif",
        "./libs/images/spin-new.svg"
      ], this is angular-cli.json file

Comment: Could you please edit your question by inserting full angular-cli.json file content

Comment: @lgorDiy i can't post whole file.. mention the portion u want so i can post that

Answer (score 3):

In case the path of the folder where you are trying to build your angular 4 application contains brackets then angular will fail to copy the files from the assets folder. It is a known issue, here is a link: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9230

Example of a failing path: *C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp*

If you change the location of the application to be build to something that does not contain brackets and build it there then it will work, in case that is possible for you to do it.

Example of a working path: *C:\Program Files\myapp*

Comment: You saved my day, trying to figure this out from a day !

Comment: It seems like there is a proper fix now, the problem was in copy-webpack-plugin package that angular uses. You will need to force update your npm lock file, more details here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9230